# How to sort records in Composite object?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

Suppose I have 2 tables in DB: Student, StudentCourse.

In meta data for Student, set StudentCourse as Composite:

```
[Include]
[Composition]
public EntityCollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
```

In Domain service for Student, inlcude StudentCourse like:

```
public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentByID(int id)
{
   reutrn this.ObjectContext.Students.Include("StudentCourse").Where(s => s.ID == id) as IQueryable<Student>;
}
```

Question is: I want to records of StudentCourse can be sorted by a column from StudentCourses, for example, CourseID.

records of StudentCourse under one student is actually an entity collection of StudentCourse.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.OrderBy(s => s.CourseId)` after `.Where(...)`?

Comment: in lambda expression, s is for Student, not StudentCourse.CourseID is not available for s.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is impossible to do even in plain SQL.
You can try if your provider will support somthing like that

```
this.ObjectContext.Students.Include("StudentCourse").Where(s => s.ID == id).OrderBy(x=> x.StudentCourse.First().CourseId) as IQueryable<Student>
```

Comment: So I don't believe a clean way to do what you want is possible. Also, even the way I suggested above it's... dummy! It would order Students by their first StudentCourse.CourseID. How useful can it be ? I'd reformulate the question to something more meaningful

Comment: Thanks. Tried and got weird error:"A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique."